# Java to Ruby (Base64/SHA1) public digest generation

Tags: java, ruby

Give a public key, I want to generate a public digest. Below is the code in JSP, but I need this in Ruby. I'm uncertain of the equivalents of SecretKeySpec, doFinal, etc. I'm using hmac, and hmac-sha1 on the Ruby end of things.

```
String pub = 'my_public_key';
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
Mac sha1Mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec publicKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(pub.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
sha1Mac.init(publicKeySpec);
byte[] publicBytes = sha1Mac.doFinal(subscriptionID.getBytes());
String publicDigest = encoder.encodeBuffer(publicBytes);
publicDigest = publicDigest.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Comment: If you have a concrete question, please edit your post to clarify it. Otherwise, this will likely be closed as "not a real question" (because it isn't).

Comment: can I upvote the do-my-bidding-minion tag?

Comment: Oh, knock it off. The snarking and quick votes to close are really unnecessary. Hint: "I'm uncertain of the equivalents of SecretKeySpec, doFinal, etc."

Comment: While I understand the reaction by CP76 & AT, as it happens Ruby does have a bit of a roadblock on this one...

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a page](http://stuff-things.net/2007/06/11/encrypting-sensitive-data-with-ruby-on-rails/) that should get you started.

By the way, I have some sympathy for [J. Riggs'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184588/j-riggs) issue. While OpenSSL does ship as part of [The Ruby Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/), it has no RDoc other than a mechanical listing of method names, and `ri OpenSSL` returns a grand total of three (3, count 'em) lines. . .

Answer (score 1):

```
sha1 = HMAC::SHA1.new( @public_key )
sha1 << data
Base64.encode64( sha1.digest )
```

Worked. Digests matched between the ruby and java examples.